# Jacobian of Dot Product - Matrices seem incorrect?

Tags: matrices, jacobian

I have the following expression

$m=A.b$ where each variable has a term $x$ inside, and these are the dimensions

> $x$ - [1x1]
>
> $b$ - [100x1]
>
> $A$ - [100x100]
>
> $m$ - [100x1]

I want to get the jacobian of $\frac{dm}{dx}$ which I assume is

$\frac{dm}{dx}=\frac{dA}{dx}.b+A.\frac{db}{dx}$

[100.1 x 1] = [100.100 x 1]*[1 x 100] + [100 x 100]*[100 x 1]

[100 x 1] = [10000 x 100] + [100 x 1] - Doesnt work

Unfortunately this doesnt add up as seen above. I am clearly doing something fundamentally wrong. Can someone please help me

Comment: All the dimensions should match up. Check your assumptions. For example, you say that b is $100 \times 1$ but then later you say it is $1 \times 100$. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Wait..so dA/dx needs to be reshaped to [100x100]?

Comment: Also..what if x was 2 dimensional? Does that mean that dA/dx becomes a tensor of size [100x100x2] or something?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.

Comment: I have never done tensor math before. I am unfamiliar how things must be ordered. Let say x was dim=2. So based on this for example I must reshape so I have [2x100x100]*[100x2] = [100x2] ?? Is this how I set it up in my code?